# Coinbase Invalid 404 request OAuth2 Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, guzzle, coinbase-api

I try make authorization in coinbase with OAuth2:

```
        $client = new Client(['cookies' => true]);
        try {
            $response = $client->request('POST', $this->urlAccessToken, [
                'headers' => [
                    'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                    'code' => $request->code,
                    'client_id' => $this->clientId,
                    'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
                    'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUri
                ]
            ]);
            dd($response->getBody());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response($e->getMessage(), 400);
        }
```

After authorization in coinbase him me redirect to redirect URI and when send request exchange code i see bad response:

> Client error: `POST http://www.coinbase.com/oauth/token` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: Invalid request. Instead of a GET request, you should be making a POST with valid POST params. For more informat (truncated...)

All code which will authorize in Coinbase:

```
private $clientId;
private $clientSecret;
private $redirectUri;
private $urlAuthorize;
private $urlAccessToken;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->clientId = env('COINBASE_CLIENT_ID');
    $this->clientSecret = env('COINBASE_CLIENT_SECRET');
    $this->redirectUri = route('oauth2-redirect');
    $this->urlAuthorize = 'https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize';
    $this->urlAccessToken = 'http://www.coinbase.com/oauth/token';
}

public function oauth(Request $request)
{
    $state = hash('sha256', $request->session()->getId());

    if (!isset($request->code)) {
        $parameters = [
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUri,
            'state' => $state
        ];

        $authorizationUrl = $this->urlAuthorize . '?' . http_build_query($parameters);

        // Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
        header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
        exit;
    } elseif (empty($request->state) || $request->state !== $state) {
        return response('Invalid state', 400);
    } else {
        $client = new Client(['cookies' => true]);
        try {
            $response = $client->request('POST', $this->urlAccessToken, [
                'headers' => [
                    'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                    'code' => $request->code,
                    'client_id' => $this->clientId,
                    'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
                    'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUri
                ]
            ]);
            dd($response->getBody());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response($e->getMessage(), 400);
        }

    }
}
```

Also i checked it in postman and him return good response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1znw5.png)

Comment: Instead of making your own coinbase client use a package !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in URL access token, need use `https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token` instead `http://www.coinbase.com/oauth/token`.